# Use a specific defaults/main.yml file

Tags: ansible

When I execute an ansible-playbook I would like to define the playbook parameters file to use.

For example define `defaults/staging.yml` instead of `defaults/main.yml`

Is it possible to set it as ansible-playbook parameter?

Comment: There are dozens ways of defining variables in Ansible. On top of that, `defaults/main.yml` is part of roles' syntax, not plays, so it's completely unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your use-case is to define variables per environment (You example looks like that)?

Ansible has a very nice way to inherit and compose variables by groups and hosts.

Have a look at `group_vars` etc. defined in the inventory or a group_vars folder: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#group-variables

Comment: thx, in some config files I have `versions:
  - directory: 2-1-1
    tag: 2.1.1b
  - directory: 2-1-2
    tag: 2.1.2b` and I use it with a `with_items`. Can I reproduce it in host file ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there are many ways to define variables, so in order to know which way might be best for you, we would need more information about your use-case.

However, let me outline another solution, which I am using within my team of developers. Imagine you are versionising your Ansible repository through Git, and for certain parameters you want to provide **sample** values, but still allow developers to **overwrite**.

In case they need to overwrite, you want to guarantee that their changes:

- persist on their setup
- are not reflected on Git repository (thus not synced to other developers)
- are easy to maintain

Here is my pattern:

```
- name: Load configuration from sample configuration file
  include_vars: ../config/config.sample.yml

- name: Check if user_specific configuration file exists
  local_action: stat path="../config/config.yml"
  register: config_st

- name: Overwrite Configuration file from local configuration file
  include_vars: ../config/config.yml
  when: config_st.stat.exists == True
```

Adding `config/config.yml` to `.gitignore`, users/developers can now have their own local parameter set, derived from a sample configuration you provide. They simply need to do `cp config.sample.yml config.yml` and modify their `config.yml`.

But sure, if you just need to select among a low number of well defined parameter sets: Just create multiple configuration files, pass a parameter to Ansible (e.g. `-e "version=1.23.45"`) and use that parameter on the `when` condition to load your variables (`include_vars: ...`).

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the include_vars module, to include a variable file to play. For example,

```
  include_vars:
    file: staging.yml
```